# Undefined offset: 0. Doctrine and native sql

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I have little problem, I want to print id of user, but I have an error: "Undefined offest: 0". Here is my code:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
$user= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
$query = $em->createNativeQuery('SELECT id FROM fos_user WHERE username_canonical = ?', $rsm);
$query->setParameter(1, $user);
$users = $query->getResult();
echo $users[0]['id'];
```

Somebody have idea what is wrong?

Comment: Error is becouse you are using user object ($user) as query parameter. Query doesn't return any user and you try to get undefinde offset.

Comment: If you already have the user object from the security context then you don't need to then find it on the database to get the id. A simple `echo $user->getId()` should give you what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `EntityResult` and `FieldResult` to `$rsm`

   ```
   $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
   $rsm->addEntityResult('App\UserBundle\Entity\User', 'u');
   $rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'id', 'id');
   ```
2. Change `setParameter`

   **$user** to  **$user->getUsernameCanonical();**
3. getResult

   ```
   foreach($users as $user)
   {
       echo $user->getId();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Change string:

```
$query->setParameter(1, $user);
```

to

```
$query->setParameter(1, $user->getUsernameCanonical());
```